# How to make a POST request in the ManyToManyField?

Tags: python, django, http

I have a UserAccess model which contains two user and articles fields. The articles field is ManyToManyField in relation to the Article model, so each user has the same list of articles associated with it. I want to change the is_blocked field using a POST request so that each article for each user is blocked individually. How to do it ?

models.py

```
    class UserAccess(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, 
                       on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
                       null=True, 
                       )
    articles = models.ManyToManyField('Article')

    def __str__(self):
      return str(self.user)

    class Meta:
      verbose_name = "access"
      verbose_name_plural = 'access'


    class Article(models.Model):
      title = models.CharField(max_length=256)
      label = models.ImageField(
        upload_to='uploads/labels', 
        blank=True, 
      )
      is_blocked = models.BooleanField(default=True)

      def __str__(self):
        if self.is_blocked == True:
          return f"‚{str(self.pk)}: {str(self.title)}"
        return f"{str(self.pk)}: {str(self.title)}"

      class Meta:
        ordering = ('pk',)
        verbose_name = "Article"
        verbose_name_plural = "Article"
```

serializers.py

```
     class ArcticleSerializer(ModelSerializer):
       class Meta:
         model = Article
         fields = [
           "pk",
           "title",
           "label",
           "is_blocked",
         ]

     class CurrentUserSerializer(ModelSerializer):
       class Meta:
         model = User
         fields = ["username"]

     class UserAccessSerializer(ModelSerializer):
       articles = ArcticleSerializer(many=True)
       user = CurrentUserSerializer(read_only=True)

       class Meta:
         model = UserAccess
         fields =[
           "user",
           "articles",
         ]
         read_only_fields = ('created','updated')
```

views.py

```
    class UserAccessViewSet(ModelViewSet):
      serializer_class =UserAccessSerializer 
      pagination_class = StandardResultsSetPagination


      def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.request.user
        return UserAccess.objects.filter(user=user)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do it with through model [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through_fields)

```
class UserAccess(models.Model):
  user = models.ForeignKey(User, 
                   on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
                   null=True, 
                   )
articles = models.ManyToManyField('Article',
                     through='ArticleBlocked',
                     through_fields=('useracces', 'article'),)

def __str__(self):
  return str(self.user)

class Meta:
  verbose_name = "access"
  verbose_name_plural = 'access'


class Article(models.Model):
  title = models.CharField(max_length=256)
  label = models.ImageField(
    upload_to='uploads/labels', 
    blank=True, 
  )
  

  def __str__(self):
    if self.is_blocked == True:
      return f"‚{str(self.pk)}: {str(self.title)}"
    return f"{str(self.pk)}: {str(self.title)}"

  class Meta:
    ordering = ('pk',)
    verbose_name = "Article"
    verbose_name_plural = "Article"


class ArticleBlocekd(models.Model):
   useracces = models.ForeignKey(UserAcces, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   article = models.ForeignKey(Articles, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   is_blocked = models.BooleanFiled(default=True)
```

This way evry pair (useracces, article) have is_blocked field

Comment: I have 20 articles that need to open one after the other sequentially, so each article has an is_blocked field. My goal is that each user would have 20 articles, with an individual field is_blocked, so that by sending POST requests each user could individually unlock each article for himself. In your example, it turns out that I can assign all the articles to only one user.

Comment: In my example you can asign evry article to evry user with is_blocked flag. But from your comment i see you want to do something like:  there is article1, article1 is blocked, article1 is asaign to many users, one of users want to edit article1 so he post is_blocked=False and then he can edit this article but other users cannot. Is this what you look for?